# Relations of newly persisted object in hibernate don't get populated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So while developing I like to use hibernates `hbm2ddl.auto=create` to create tables for me on the fly, without investing too much time.
But I ran into a problem with this now, at startup the tables are created and I fill them with some dummy values, for example my Category entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema", name = "Categories")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
public class Category extends AuditRecord<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7827654543297324983L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="ID_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="id",updatable=false,nullable=false)
    protected Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentCategory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Category parentCategory;

    private String nameTranslationKey;

    private String descriptionTranslationKey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Category> subCategories;// = new ArrayList<>();

    //getters & setters
}
```

Which is populated with:

```
Category cat = new Category();
cat.setNameTranslationKey("rootCat");
service.saveObjectDirectly(cat);

Category subCat = new Category();
subCat.setParentCategory(cat);
subCat.setNameTranslationKey("subcat1");
service.saveObjectDirectly(subCat);
subCat = new Category();
subCat.setParentCategory(cat);
subCat.setNameTranslationKey("subcat2");
service.saveObjectDirectly(subCat);
```

`service.saveObjectDirectly` simply starts a transaction (if none is open), uses `entityManager.persist(entity)` and commits the transaction.
Now later I try to load the `rootCat` and am faced with the problem that the subcategories list is null.
If I don't create the tables on startup etc I can retrieve the `rootCat` just fine and the subcategories are populated.

I can't understand why this should be the case. Has anyone an explanation for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you should uncomment `= new ArrayList<>();`. That list shoud really never be null, even when creating a brand new category. It seems you're reloading rootCat in the same transaction, or in the same persistence context at least, as the one used to populate the database initially. So it all boils down to how you get and manage your entity manager and your transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't add the `subcat` object to the `cat` objects subcategories (e.g. `cat.getSubCategories().add(subcat)`). Maybe if I would've refreshed the `rootCat` object when fetching from the Database it would've been correct, didn't test that.

Just wanted to let others know.